# Change chart background daily

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to differentiate with different colors on a daily basis? for example, Nov 9th chart has a background color of Red and Nov 10th will have green and so on as new days gets added, they can get different colors or repeated patterns of colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice colorful question :)
This should plot what you're looking for.

```
//@version=4
study("DayColors", overlay=true)

var color c0     = input(color.silver, "Sunday",    type=input.color)
var color c1     = input(color.red,    "Monday",    type=input.color)
var color c2     = input(color.orange, "Tuesday",   type=input.color)
var color c3     = input(color.yellow, "Wednesday", type=input.color)
var color c4     = input(color.green,  "Thursday",  type=input.color)
var color c5     = input(color.blue,   "Friday",    type=input.color)
var color c6     = input(color.purple, "Saturday",  type=input.color)
var int   transp = input(60, "Background transparancy", minval=0, maxval=100)

var arrColor     = array.new_color()

if barstate.isfirst
    array.push(arrColor, c0)
    array.push(arrColor, c1)
    array.push(arrColor, c2)
    array.push(arrColor, c3)
    array.push(arrColor, c4)
    array.push(arrColor, c5)
    array.push(arrColor, c6)

bgcolor(array.get(arrColor, dayofweek-1), transp)
```

Edit: As requested in the comments, apply colors only from Market open to Market close.

```
//@version=4
study("DayColors", overlay=true)

var color c0       = input(color.silver, "Sunday",    type=input.color)
var color c1       = input(color.red,    "Monday",    type=input.color)
var color c2       = input(color.orange, "Tuesday",   type=input.color)
var color c3       = input(color.yellow, "Wednesday", type=input.color)
var color c4       = input(color.green,  "Thursday",  type=input.color)
var color c5       = input(color.blue,   "Friday",    type=input.color)
var color c6       = input(color.purple, "Saturday",  type=input.color)
var int   transp   = input(60, "Background transparancy", minval=0, maxval=100)
var       sess     = input("1800-1700:12345", "Session", type=input.session) // Asia session Monday to Friday
var       arrColor = array.new_color()
var int   t        = na

if barstate.isfirst
    array.push(arrColor, c0)
    array.push(arrColor, c1)
    array.push(arrColor, c2)
    array.push(arrColor, c3)
    array.push(arrColor, c4)
    array.push(arrColor, c5)
    array.push(arrColor, c6)

t := time(timeframe.period, sess)

bgcolor(na(t) ? na : array.get(arrColor, dayofweek-1), transp)
```

Comment: Thanks, This is great.  Is there a way to do it from Market open to Market close? ( time:   6pm to 5:pm)

Comment: I've added a code example that applies the color between certain hours. Those hours can be modified (inputs).